# Centering and aligning a list of items with image and text in react native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

So, I've got the following code:

```
export const MenuWrapper = styled.ScrollView`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
`

export const Item = styled(MyButton)`
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: black;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: ${remToPx(0.5)}px 0;
  width: 80%;
  margin: ${remToPx(1)}px auto;
  justify-content: center;
`
```

with MYBUtton just being a pressable and

```
<View>
      <Header title={event.name} noSub />
      <MenuWrapper>
        <Item>
          <ImageWrapper
            h_size={1.5}
            w_size={1.5}
            source={require('../../../assets/icons/home/programacao.png')}
          />
          <View>
            <MyText color="white">Programação</MyText>
          </View>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <ImageWrapper
            h_size={1.5}
            w_size={1.5}
            source={require('../../../assets/icons/home/copanela.png')}
          />
          <MyText color="white">CoPanela</MyText>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <ImageWrapper
            h_size={1.5}
            w_size={1.5}
            source={require('../../../assets/icons/home/recompensas.png')}
          />
          <MyText color="white">Recompensas</MyText>
        </Item>
      </MenuWrapper>
    </View>
```

that generates the following:

[image]

The idea is to have all of them centered, but each image basically on the same column. In normal CSS I'd use a grid and everything would be fine, but here I cant seem to find a way to solve the problem showcased at the different alignment of "Programação" and "Copanela".

I've tried many solutions such as using two other views inside the item with each having 50% of the button and some align-right align-left shenanigans but it didn't work.

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want to have your button text centered as it is set now with justify-content: center but icons for that text in same column. Or you want everything to be aligned to flex-start (btw you use justify-content twice in your style props, which may be the case)

Comment: Didn't see I was using it twice haha but that has no effect since the center overwrites the other one. The idea is to have both the image and the text as centered as possible, but all the icons aligned on the same column. It doesn't need to be with justify-content: center, tho

Comment: Make MenuItem position: "relative", add styling for IconWrapper position: "absolute" and set left: 0 option (or whatever suits you).

Comment: That helped, but I ended up putting the image and the text inside another div with a fixed width and just centered that instead! Thanks for the consideration, however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take another view with fixed width inside button

Comment: Yeah! Ended up doing exactly that